# calculate how many leave hours an employee took in a day

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa

So i have the following table for an employee Leave :

```
id  numberOfDays approved     end_date           reason       start_date           employee_id
1   6             true    "2022-05-31 11:00:00" "sickness"  "2022-05-24 10:00:00"   8
2   0.25          true    "2022-05-17 14:00:00" "sickness"  "2022-05-13 09:00:00"   8
3   1             true    "2022-05-11 08:00:00" "family"    "2022-05-09 08:00:00"   8
```

Given a specific date (day) , I want to calculate how many leave hours did that employee take. **( a work day is from 08:00 -> 12:00 and 14:00 -> 18:00 )**

for example, for employee_id = 8 and day = "2022-24-2022" , my desired output would be 6 hours because the leave started from 2022-05-24 at 10:00

for employee_id=8 and day "2022-05-31", output would be 3 hours ( the employee didnt work from 08:00 to 11:00 )

for employee_id=8 and day="2022-05-09" , output would be 8

Comment: Is `2022-24-2022` supposed to be `2022-05-24`?

Comment: What are the working hours?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, mb

Comment: @DaminiSuthar an employee can work for 8 hours a day ( from 08:00 to 18:00, with 12:00 to 14:00 being lunch hours )

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tsrange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) and its operators to find the overlap between working hours and leaves.

Example query (untested, but it should help pointing you in the right direction):

```
WITH rng AS ((SELECT tsrange([input_date] + INTERVAL '8 hour', [input_date] + INTERVAL '12 hour', '[)') as r
         UNION
         (SELECT tsrange([input_date] + INTERVAL '14 hour', [input_date] + INTERVAL '18 hour', '[)') as r)
SELECT 
SUM(extract('epoch' FROM upper(rng.r * tsrange([your table].start_date, [your table].end_date, '[)') - lower(rng.r * tsrange([your table].start_date, [your table].end_date, '[)'))/3600)
FROM [your table]
INNER JOIN rng ON rng.r && tsrange([your table].start_date, [your table].end_date, '[)')
WHERE [your table].employee_id = 8
```

Explanation:

1. the "rng" CTE contains the working hour ranges for the desired date (8-12 and 14-18)
2. this is joined with the main table via the [tsrange && operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-range.html), which returns true if the ranges overlap
3. the tsrange * operator is used to get the intersection between working hours and leave interval
4. the duration of the resulting tsrange is computed by subtracting its lower bound from its upper bound
5. the resulting interval is converted to numeric hours via extract('epoch' /3600)